# "adb version" and "which adb" giving 2 different paths

Tags: android, adb

I'm using Android Studio for a project, and I'm new to the Android development ecosystem. I'm having difficulty understanding what is going on with my adb paths.

First, I have WSL on my Windows PC, and I have installed adb via "sudo apt-get install adb".

When I do "adb version" it prints out:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

But when I do "which adb" it prints out:
/usr/bin/lib

I'm confused because where does /usr/bin/lib come from? Why doesn't "which adb" print out the 1st one?

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/lib` ? Run `ls -l /usr/bin/lib`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano No such file or directory exists. Doesn't look like lib/ exists.

Comment: And `which adb` returns something that doesn't exit?